# While loop not continuing - socket

Tags: java, sockets

Okay, so I'm creating a rather simple java application, which will eventually turn into an online 2-player texas hold'em game. Right now, I'm trying to send some simple messages over network to make sure the basic functionality is working. I am however stuck.

I've got two methods in a class. One for the serverside (or really a hybrid between a client and a server), and one for the clientside. They connect together fine. As I made this, I noticed that when I connected, they both spammed their default messages (right now being "CLIENT: Started" and "SERVER: Started" back and forth to eachother. I figured this was because the string containing that information was never emptied, and so they never knew when to stop transmitting it. I then made sure that after sending the message, that variable was nulled, and a check was made to see if it was null before sending.
Here's where it went wrong though! After doing that, they won't send more than one message at all. They send their respective welcome messages, but anything I try to transmit after that is ignored. It's almost like if the while-loop for the server/client stops.

So, I have two public variable declared in the class. These contain any message the server or client wishes to send.

`public static String serverCommand = null;`

`public static String clientCommand = null;`

They are null by default, but changed during runtime in the GUI-part.
The server loop looks like this:

```
                while(true)
                {
                    if((receive = receiveStream.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(receive);
                    }
                    if(serverCommand != null)
                    {
                        printer.println(serverCommand);
                        printer.flush();
                        Network.serverCommand = null;
                    }
                }
```

And the client while loop like this:

```
                while(true)
                {
                    if(Network.clientCommand != null)
                    {
                        printer.println(clientCommand);
                        printer.flush();
                        Network.clientCommand = null;
                    }

                    if((receive = receiveStream.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(receive);
                    }
                }
```

However, as mentioned - after `Network.clientCommand` is set to null the first time around, it never again sends any messages, even though `Network.clientCommand` changes due to user input during runtime.

I'll post two links to the complete sourcecode of the client/server-part of this below, as they're a bit too big to paste here.

**LINK:**  http://hastebin.com/oqotirufic.java

Does anyone here have any idea what's happening, and how should I think when trying to fix/get around it? I'll add that my experience with both Java and network programming is very limited.

**EDIT**

I'll add the part of the GUI which acccesses/changes the variables.
http://hastebin.com/upadayuwug.java

Comment: Where is `Network.clientCommand` set to anything != null ?

Comment: how is clientCommand get changed?

Comment: They are both changed through a GUI. It's in a different class.
I know they are both changed since if I remove the setting to null in the example above, they both change (but keep spamming obviously)

**Edit**

Added the GUI part in the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course after `Network.clientCommand` is null, nothing more is sent — that's what you told it to do:

```
if((receive = receiveStream.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(receive);
}
```

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), `readLine()` returns

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Not "`null` if there's a pause in transmission". If it hasn't yet seen a full line, or the end of the stream (socket disconnection), well, then it's not done yet. It waits until it gets the full line of input before it goes to the next line of your code.

But how do you know if you should wait for a message to come in, or send out the next one? *You can't*. You can't depend on when or if anything will arrive from the other side.

What happens when both sides have nothing to send? They both start waiting to receive. What happens when one side gets something new to send? Well, once it receives something, it'll send it. But that never happens!

What you can do, is call `readLine()` in a separate thread. See the [JavaDocs for `Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and the Java Tutorial Lesson ["Concurrency"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). And if you're using Swing for your GUI, also see the Java Tutorial Lesson ["Concurrency in Swing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Look at that! Makes perfect sense, kudos for explaining that so well too!
I looked into creating a separate thread for the readLine()-call, and added that for both the server and client. It however still won't receive any new messages past the first "SERVER: Started" and "CLIENT: Started". http://hastebin.com/enilezakoq.java is the updated example. Could you offer any further advice?

Comment: Adding on, I've done a bit more digging. Seems serverCommand and clientCommand is always `null` inside of the actual while-loop. It never manages to change during runtime. It's almost as if it gets stuck - any clue?

Comment: If you're writing to and reading from fields in different threads, without any synchronization, you can't guarantee when the value you've written in one thread will be visible in the other thread. The reading thread could just continue to think it's reading the old value. Looks like what you really want to do is pass commands in to the thread that writes them, so that they get written in order, so using something like a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) might be better.

Comment: Thank you guys! First, I put it in a separate thread. I also separated the writing to clients to its own function, that is not run into a loop. This was made possible by instantiating the sockets in the class instead of in the function, meaning I can get more widespread use. Marking as correct answer as it's actually the thing I did.